# Get number from substring not using JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, numbers

I tried to solve this substring

```
"sIDHistory": [ "21 34 49234328 9"  ]
```

I need to get the number and push them into a new array . But I can't use json.parse . Any help ? Thanks

Comment: Out of curiosity, why can't use use `JSON.parse` ?

Comment: Because in the website we had some issue regarding parse . And I'm trying to solve taking number directly from string and not converting and then get the obj values

Comment: Is that a single number inside the string or multiple?

Answer (score 0):

Basically we need to split the string wherever there are spaces, and filter out `Not a number` instances -:

```
let strArr = `"sIDHistory": [ "21 34 49234328 9" ]`
strArr = strArr.split(" ").filter(i => !isNaN(parseInt(i)));
```

Comment: What will `"21` and `19"` be parsed as?

Comment: Since `parseInt` is being used inside `isNaN` both will be translated to 21 and 19 respectively

Comment: My bad it should be `strArr`, I changed it in the answer

Answer (score 0):

Would be great to know whether your String contains one or multiple numbers. Also whether the array can contain more than one string.

```js
let str = `"sIDHistory": [ "21 34 49234328 9"]`,
    res = str.match(/\d+/g).join("")

console.log(res)
```

```js
let str = `"sIDHistory": [ "21 34 49234328 9"]`,
    res = str.match(/\d+/g).map(v => +v);

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let obj= {"sIDHistory": [ "21 34 49234328 9"  ]}

let numArr=obj.sIDHistory[0].split(" ").map(num=>parseInt(num));

console.log(numArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the only number from any complex string using this.
This will help:-

```
var strVal = `"sIDHistory": [ "21 34 49234328 9"  ]`;
var numVal = strVal.match(/\d/g);
numVal = numVal.join("");
console.log(numVal);
```

OutPut:2134492343289